# Is it possible to check who and when removed column from particular sharepoint 2010 list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to check who and when removed column from particular sharepoint 2010 list?

How to do it if it is possible?

[UPDATE 1] Auditing is disabled. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by analyzing IIS logs. Here's the sample:
GET /_layouts/listedit.aspx List=%7BF9E34AA3%2DE564%2D425A%2D93E3%2DC242B4AD7F5D%7D - means user is accessing the list settings page.

GET /_layouts/FldEdit.aspx List=%7BF9E34AA3%2DE564%2D425A%2D93E3%2DC242B4AD7F5D%7D&Field=textB
- this is the next step. User is editing textB field.

POST /_layouts/mngfield.aspx i=1&Cmd=DeleteField&List=%7BF9E34AA3%2DE564%2D425A%2D93E3%2DC242B4AD7F5D%7D&Field=textB
- user is removing textB field from the list.

List parameter contains ID of the list so the first step is getting the ID of your list. Information you can get from IIS log depends on how is he configured but username and IP is standard info logged.